# Partial functions keeping their signature

Tags: r, currying, partial-application

We can use `purrr::partial` to create partial functions:

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  print(x)
  print(y)
  return(invisible())
}

ff <- purrr::partial(f, y = 1)

ff(2)
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This can often be quite useful, but has the unfortunate side-effect that the partialized function loses it's signature, which is replaced with an elipsis:

```r
ff
#> <partialised>
#> function (...) 
#> f(y = 1, ...)
```

While programatically irrelevant, this leads to worse code legibility during development, where RStudio's "intellisense" can no longer aid us in remembering the names and/or order of arguments. So is there some other means of partializing which keeps the original signature (minus the partialized-away arguments), as below?

```r
ff
#> <partialised>
#> function (x) 
#> f(y = 1, x)
```

Now, obviously this can be done manually, by defining a new function `ff` which is simply a wrapper around `f` with the desired arguments.

```r
ff <- function(x) f(x, y = 1)
```

But this means any modifications to the signature of `f` need to be replicated to `ff`. So is there a "cleaner" way of partializing while keeping the signature?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `rlang::fn_fmls()` (or `base::formals()` equivalent) to explicitly give default values to the function arguments:

```
# If desired, create a copy of the function first: ff <- f
rlang::fn_fmls(f) <- purrr::list_modify( rlang::fn_fmls(f), y=1 )

args(f)
# function (x, y = 1) 

f(2)
# [1] 2
# [1] 1
```